# find and replace a word with another in all file names of a directory

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I'm trying to replace the word "owner" with "user" in all file names of my directory (and in all subdirectories).

Ex.

```
owners_controller => users_controller
owner.rb => user.rb
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I've tried this: grep -rl 'owner' . | xargs sed -i 's/owner/user/g'    but that only applies to the words in the file, not the file names themselves

Comment: try something like this  find / -name 'program.c'  |grep owner |xargs .

Answer (score 2):

Use `find` with the `-exec` option to call `rename` on every file and subdirectory containing "*owner*" in its name:

```
find path/to/my/directory/ -depth -name "*owner*" -exec /usr/bin/rename owner user {} \+
```

If you don't have `rename`, you can use a `mv` command with `bash` parameter expansion:

```
find path/to/my/directory/ -depth -name "*owner*" -exec \
  bash -c 'mv "{}" $(old="{}"; new="${old##*/}"; echo "${old%/*}/${new/owner/user}")' \;
```

`bash -c '...'` invokes the bash shell on the one-liner surrounded by single-quotes. The one-liner acts as a `mv` command that renames all occurrences of "*owner*" in the basename of the matching filename/subdirectory to "*user*".

Specifically, `find` substitutes every `{}` after the `-exec` with the matching file/subdirectory's pathname. Here `mv` accepts two arguments; the first is `{}` (described previously), and the second is a string returned from a sub-shell `$(...)` containing three bash commands. These bash commands use [parameter expansion techniques](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to rename the basename of `{}`.

Comment: Probably need the `-depth` option to `find` in order to prevent failures when a subdirectory is renamed, resulting in it's files no longer being accessible under the old location...

Comment: I already specified `-type f`. Pretty sure that'll prevent subdirectories from being passed to `rename`.

Comment: I may have misread OP's "and in all subdirectories" to mean subdirectory renames were expected... If it's truly just files to get renamed, then `-depth` is not necessary (although it won't hurt anything either)...

Comment: You're right; the question's phrasing is vague. If the OP means "filenames as well as subdirectories" then `-type f` should be replaced with `-depth`.

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant "filenames as well as subdirectories"

Comment: Right now, I'm getting this: find: rename: No such file or directory

Comment: There are multiple `rename` commands, none of them standard. Install one of them, or write your own; it's not hard for this limited case.

Comment: @user1411469 Use mv command instead of rename. It is more commonly used.

Comment: Updated my solution to use `bash` and `mv` for when `rename` isn't available.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have `rename` installed, this should be a reasonable alternative (assuming `bash` as your shell):

```
while read entry
do
  mv "${entry}" "${entry/owner/user}"
done < <(find . -depth -name '*owner*' -print)
```